# Apache Ignite on Kubernetes with NFS storage - should I choose a different storage?

Tags: docker

I am experimenting with deploying Apache Ignite on a test Kubernetes cluster that uses Docker CE as its container engine, that has a [nfs-client-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client) providing volumes to any PVCs a dynamic app may require. Used [this instruction](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/stateful-deployment) to create the deployment, added extra configuration with a configmap, now Ignite says this in logs:

```
Oct 29, 2019 7:02:40 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: Unable to acquire lock to file [/persistence], reason: I/O error
```

That is, it tries to request a write lock on an NFS-mounted file/folder and naturally fails. I have discovered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265717/docker-mount-nfs-with-local-lock-all) asking for NFS locks within Docker, which also states that Docker cannot mount NFS with locks for some reason. My NFS server is a cluster of Nutanix CE, the only available protected storage I have at the moment. I wonder, is there a way to make Apache Ignite not ask for locks on its persistent storage, provided the storage is secured enough so they are just not needed anymore? Or I should have used another storage provider, something that can provide write locks to file entities to containerized apps?